# Problem in displaying with Embedded Google Docs Viewer module

Tags: 7

I'm using Embedded Google Docs Viewer module,everything is ok except when viewing it's showing like this:
[image]

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `PPTX` file and Save As a `PPT` file.  This worked for me to prevent the unexpected symbols in the google docs viewer when trying to embed a `PPTX` file.

Answer (score 0):

Can the PDF be accessed?  Is it behind a password?  Are the permissions correct on the file?

If you try with another PDF does the same thing happen?

e.g

www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.pdf

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.pdf

~Mark

Comment: i tried to upload a pdf file it's working perfectly but when i trying to upload a pptx file it's look like the image i posted above.

Comment: Are there any strange characters in your file name?  If you try and hit the file directly using the full domain + filepath does it download?

Comment: the file name is text and it's not include any strange characters in it's content, it's just  a one slide contain a few words. it's uploaded but it's look the same.